How to keep the system-wide vimrc for the brew-installed Vim between updates?
The brew-installed Vim (as of version 9.1) uses /opt/homebrew/share/vim/vimrc as the location for the system-wide vimrc file (according to the output of vim --version). This file is not included in the package, but the top-level directory in its path is a symlink to a version-specific directory:
$ ls -l /opt/homebrew/share/vim
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 user  admin  32 Nov 13 11:41 /opt/homebrew/share/vim -> ../Cellar/vim/9.1.0850/share/vim

Thus, upgrading Vim requires re-creating the global vimrc each time, which is very annoying. Is there a way to keep a global config file, while allowing the Vim package upgrades?

Are you intentionally upgrading this or is it a side effect of brew wanting to keep everything updated?

I usually just use brew upgrade to upgrade all packages from time to time. Apparently, a workaround may be to pin the vim package to a specific version so that it never get upgraded. I'll do that if I don't find a better solution.

That should have a bug filed @Homebrew.  If you're going to go to the trouble to create that structure, why is it version-specific?
